# Is there a way to get the progress of a file transfer using move function in a Perl script?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, progress, file-transfer

I am an ETL developer and I deal with a lot of data that needs to be processed from one form to the other before it can be loaded into tables. Therefore, most of the scripts that I work with, at some point, have to move a file from one place to the other. We are a windows shop. I was wondering if there was a way to see how much time a move takes when I am using the move function in Perl. If I need to call a windows command through system that will give me this option, then I am ok to use that as well. Is there anything in Perl or windows command line that will tell me the progress of the file transfer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Win32::FileOp](http://search.cpan.org/~jenda/Win32-FileOp-0.14.1/FileOp.pm) package from cpan.

Here's a relevant excerpt:

> **CopyConfirm**
>
> ```
>  CopyConfirm ($FileName => $FileOrDirectoryName [, ...])
>  CopyConfirm (\@FileNames => $DirectoryName [, ...] )
>  CopyConfirm (\@FileNames => \@FileOrDirectoryNames [, ...])
> ```
>
> Copies the specified files. In case of a collision, shows a
>   confirmation dialog. Shows progress
>   dialogs.
>
> Returns true if successful.
>
> **MoveConfirm**
>
> Moves the specified files. Parameters as CopyConfirm

A command line alternative would be [Term::ProgressBar](http://search.cpan.org/~fluffy/Term-ProgressBar-2.09/lib/Term/ProgressBar.pm), which is also a lot more flexible, but somewhat harder to set up. You would have to do something like: get the original file's size, then start the copy and poll the new file's size (from a child process) to give updates to the progress bar.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely what I was looking for. Now I need some spare time to implement this on all the scripts I have.